# firebase ssl generation takes over 24 hours

Tags: ssl, dns, firebase-hosting

Its a pity google does not offer its domain service in Germany, otherwise launching a react website vial firebase would really be super easy, great service! 
The only problem I faced is that the SSL generation seam not to work as described in the documentation.
In Firebase Hosting it keeps on saying: **Needs setup**
And the documentations says on that topic:

> In most cases, your DNS A records haven't propagated from your domain
>   name provider to Firebase Hosting servers. Troubleshooting tip: If
>   it's been more than 24 hours, check that you've pointed your records
>   to Firebase Hosting.

By pointing the records I assume they mean adding two A Type files with provided IP´s.
I added those more than 24 Hours ago and they are as valid as they can be, I checked them multiple times now on my DNS provider checkdomain.de.
Or am I getting something wrong here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: If you run `dig -t txt +noall +answer <your-domain-name>`, what does the output show. That is the closest to what Firebase Hosting sees, so if that is not showing the correct A records yet, it won't work. If you think the output looks correct, edit your question to include the output, so we can have a look.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen One should first specifically check the authoritative nameservers to make sure the records are published. Then only checking recursive nameservers.

Comment: There is no "propagation".  Things will depend on your zone TTL, both the negative one (in the SOA minimum field) and the TTL of records that change. You can lower them before doing a change.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen when I run your prompt I get: <my-domain-name>  300 IN TXT "google-site-verification=y1..." which does not include any information about A, so is checkdomain.de filtering the files out for what ever reason?

Comment: Ah, yes. The command was for checking `TXT` records only. To get the `A` records, use `dig +noall +answer <your-domain-name>`. If you tell your domain it may be faster to help. Failing that, it might be better to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen this prompt returns the A files with expected values, but there is one A file more, which I can't see in my interface. I do not have any Support Plan, so I hoped I can fix the problem this way and help others which should happen to be in the same situation.

Comment: Actually the IP listed in that A file does match one defined in a different form for the main IP address, so maybe I should remove it there or change by the google one, but which, google has to, and non IPv6 ones

Comment: Firebase has free support, and they're specialized in these cases.

Comment: ok thanks, I`ll try to find them.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, the problem was that the provider had an additional field outside of the "repository scope" which was titled main IP. This IP also translated into a A entry which could be discovered by the prompt suggested by @FrankvanPuffelen (thanks for that):

```
dig +noall +answer <your-domain-name>
```

One the field value has also been changed to one of the IP's provided by firebase the SSL Certificate has been successfully generated.

I hope that it does help someone else in the same situation and I'll try to convince firebase support to add those hints to the documentation.